# Parse SaveBefore on User not working

Tags: parse-platform

I have been trying to run this simple code on my parse cloud code.
All it has to do is save a string value when creating the user, I see the code on my cloud code but when I create the user nothing is being saved.

This is the code:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(“Parse.User”, function(request, response) {
request.object.set(“lcUserName”, “eitan”);
response.success();
});
```

I will be happy to receive any advice you have.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(“Parse.User”, function(request, response) {
```

To this:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
```

I don't think you need quotes for Parse's default classes.

> Source:  I have some cloud code that does the same for `Parse.Installation` and runs fine.

If that doesn't work, it's possibly a permissions issue, try calling:

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```

Before you set your key and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: sadly it didnt wokred as well but thanks.
I already have a couple of cloud code on the user class to check if the user is unique and it works. this one dose not for some reason

Comment: Oh, let's try to set your master key and see if that helps. (see answer)

Comment: No luck nither, Is there a change it could be about the default ACL?
do you know if there is a way to see if the code was running at all?